# Unable to send excel attachment by Gmail using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail, google-oauth, google-workspace

I am using Google Apps Script (*.gs) to send mail via Gmail. Mails are working file and even attachments using images available in public URL are working fine.
I am using

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("Google file ID")
```

to get the file and attach. I am getting the error

> The feature you are attempting to use has been disabled by your domain administrator.

I am the admin and want to understand exactly where do I enable this feature. Can someone guide me please.

Addtionally, I checked my Google script Code's **project properties** and found that the following 4 OAuth Scopes are required by the script: Here are the scopes and next to them the response when I try accessing these in my browser.

1. https://mail.google.com/
   -- Able to access mails.
2. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
   -- The text "drive" appears in the top of the browser
3. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
   -- The page gives error "Not Found. Error 404"
4. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly
   -- The page gives error "Not Found. Error 404"

Here are 3 scenarios I have tried. the 3rd one fails.

1. Send mail without any attachment: WORKS PROPERLY.

```
function SimpleMail(){
  GmailApp.sendEmail(<recipient email>, 'MAIL without any ATTACHMENT', 
 'Hi, \nPlease see mail without any attachment' )  
}
```

2. Send mail with attachment from a public URL: WORKS FINE with Attached image.

```
function sendAttachment(){
        var attachmentUlr = "<URL of an Image on a public facing website>" ;
        var fileBlob = UrlFetchApp
          .fetch(attachmentUlr)
          .getBlob()
          .setName("fileBlob"+'.jpg');  
        GmailApp.sendEmail(<recipient email>, 'MAIL with ATTACHMENT', 
 'Hi, \nPlease see mail with image from a website as attachment', {attachments:[fileBlob]})
}
```

3. With attachment from my Google Drive URL: FAILS,

```
function sendAttachment(){
        var attachmentUlr = DriveApp.getFileById('<Google File ID>');
        var fileBlob = UrlFetchApp
            .fetch(attachmentUlr)
            .getBlob()
            .setName("fileBlob"+'.xlsx');  
        GmailApp.sendEmail(<recipient email>, 'MAIL with ATTACHMENT', 
 'Hi, \nPlease see mail with file from Drive as attachment', {attachments:[fileBlob]})
}
```

Comment: Please add an [mcve] (add the code of a complete but minimal function that reproduces the problem)

Comment: @Rubén, I have added code snippets now. Hope you find it useful.

Comment: How are you calling the function (from the script editor, a custom menu, ...)? Are you signed-in into multiple accounts? Have you already tried using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved once I enabled Drive SDK API as an admin.
Got to admin panel > Apps > G Suite > Settings for Drive and Docs > Features And Applications.
Enable / Check on the box - "Allow users to access Google Drive with the Drive SDK API".

Once this setup was enabled, my code was able to pick the file from google drive for attachment.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't return the file URL

```
DriveApp.getFileById('<Google File ID>')
```

that explains why the third code example fails

Try this

```
function sendAttachment(){
   var file = DriveApp.getFileById('<Google File ID>');
   var fileBlob = file.getBlob();
   GmailApp.sendEmail(
      <recipient email>, 
      'MAIL with ATTACHMENT', 
      'Hi, \nPlease see mail with file from Drive as attachment', 
      {attachments:[fileBlob]}
   )
}
```

Related

- [Send email with picture attachment and body using google script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41278530/1595451)
- [Sending Multiple attachments with Google Script from Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19135885/1595451)

Comment: The code is fine. Even with the revised code given by you, I am getting the same error "The feature you are attempting to use has been disabled by your domain administrator." . Need to know where I can enable this permission.